# Rails validation variable proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, lambda, proc

```
:inclusion => {:in => r = (1..15), :min => r.first, :max => r.last}
```

This is working code I have. The thing I wanted to make dynamic is the "15" part, e.g

> :inclusion => {:in => r = (1..Vehicle.max_passengers), :min => r.first, :max => r.last}

I have defined the following class method:

```
def self.max_passengers
   15
end
```

Of course it didn't work. I've tried using Procs and lambdas, but It didn't work properly for me. :( 
Can someone help me with this one - is it possible ?

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting? Because the change you posted looks fine to me.

Comment: Bad value for range :) Or something like that. I got it working ... but I cannot get the "r" values: r.first, r.last. When I remove them it works, but when they are present, it throws, that there is no method max_passengers for Class::class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [custom validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def self.validates_max_passenger(attr_name, r)
    validates attr_name, :inclusion => { :in => r, :min => r.first, :max => r.last } }
  end
end

# later in your class of choice:      
validates_max_passenger :passengers, 1..5
```

Or, you can try the following with lambda

```
def self.max_passengers
   1..15
end  


validates :attrib, :inclusion => {:in => lambda { |obj| ClassName.max_passengers } }
```

Note that you won't need the min/max if you're using `:in` on range.

Comment: How about defining a constant? e.g:
`MAX_PASSENGERS = 15` then:
`:inclusion => {:in => r = (1..MAX_PASSENGERS), :min => r.first, :max => r.last}` 

I think that's what you were trying to achieve with your class method.

Comment: Thank you. Thats an option as well. It's just, I know for a fact, that, for example, this construction WILL work: 
def self.max_passengers
    (1..10)
  end
And then, using lambda or proc, it would be embedded properly. I just can't get it, why is it that different, when I want only part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `validates_with` is of any help.This helper passes the record to a separate class for validation in which you can make your validation criteria dynamic i.e by reading some config or so on.
More info on `validates_with` is available at ruby on rails [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with GoodnessValidator
end

class GoodnessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
     # implement your dynamic criteria here                 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inclusion: { in: proc { 1..Vehicle.max_passengers } }
```